# How to convert bytes object to string and then Decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to convert the bytes object to `Decimal`. In order to achieve it, I am firstly converting it to string. Below is my function to convert it to string.

```
def strPrepare(self, s):
    return str(s).strip()
```

Then I am calling this function as:

```
x = b'6016.0000'
s = self.strPrepare(x)
d = Decimal(s)
```

But with this code I am getting the error as:

> Error has occurred: Cannot convert b'6016.0000' to Decimal

Comment: How do you use this function? Are you sure it's that function that causes the error? It says something about conversion to Decimal, but your function only converts to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) from [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) object, you need to firstly decode your [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) object using [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) function as:

```
>>> my_bytes = b'6016.0000'

>>> my_str = my_bytes.decode()
# where `my_str` holds the string value `'6016.0000'`
```

Or you may get the same result by passing [`encoding`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) parameter while type-casting your bytes object to string as:

```
>>> my_str = str(my_bytes, encoding='utf-8')
# Here also `my_str` holds the string value `'6016.0000'`
```

As the [Python's `str` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) says:

> if object is a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) (or [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)) object, then [`str(bytes, encoding, errors)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) is equivalent to [`bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Then in order to type-cast your number string `my_str` to [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), you may simply do:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> Decimal(my_str)
Decimal('6016.0000')
```

---

In your code, when you type-casted a bytes object using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) without the `encoding` parameter, it returned you a new string having `b'...'` at the start as:

```
>>> str(my_bytes)
"b'6016.0000'"
```

This behavior is also mentioned in [Python's `str` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> Passing a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object to [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) without the encoding or errors arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string representation (see also the [`-b` command-line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-b) to Python).

Comment: `Error has occurred: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
`

Comment: Sure, I have run

Comment: @Fama Clear your console and rerun the program. My guess is you are assigning `my_bytes = b'6016.0000'` without `b` before the string. But the example you shared in the question contains `b` before it showing it is `bytes` object and not string object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strip(), try `Decimal(s.decode())`. This makes the bytes object `b'6016.0000'` a string and should work great.

Comment: `Error has occurred: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'`